# Check if a UIScrollVIew's contentOffset is equal to a certain x value

Tags: ios, objective-c, scrollview

I have a UIScrollView inside a UICollectionViewCell an I'm trying to perform an action when a UIScrollView scrolls to a certain -x value.

I've tried

```
CGPoint lastOffset;

if (lastOffset.x < -50 && scrollView.contentOffset.x >= -50) {
    // Animate the star
    NSLog(@"Animate");
}
```

but the problem is that it only gets called when the scrollVIew is returning to its normal state.

for the heck of it, I've also tried

```
if (scrollView.contentOffset.x >= -50) {
    // Animate the star
    NSLog(@"Animate");
}
```

but this doesn't always get called.

Basically, what I am trying to create is something like the pull to refresh, but on the scrollViews's x access.

Another example if what I am trying to do is what Tweetbot 3 for iPhone does. If you swipe right on a cell you get the options to reply, star, etc etc.

Whats the best way to solve this?

**Update:** I'm using a UICollectionViewCell.

The way the scrollview is set up is something like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to bring the gutter view in :

[image]

and animate a little star when the scrollView reaches -50 on the x axis.

The reason why I'm placing this view and the animating the star in the negative part of the scrollView's content bounds, is to allow the scrollView to snap back into place.

**Update 2:** I've figured it out. I'll accept my answer soon as I am allowed to. Thanks for everyone's input!

Comment: Have you tried using the UIScrollViewDelegate and using you calculations in the scrollViewDidScroll: method?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html

Comment: @Chris That is where it is placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (lastOffset.x > -50 && scrollView.contentOffset.x <= -50) {
    // Animate the star
    NSLog(@"Animate");
}
```

I wasn't checking to see if the lastOffest.x was greater than -50, I was checking if it was less.

Answer (score 0):

I've also have the same problem，this is my solution。

1:addsubview into scrollview,not full screen. because scrollview and tableview will call touch event(ps: U can get touch object in touch event).
just like this :## Heading ##[image]

2:U can detect user touch time,such as >=3s call scrollview another call tableview. but that is  less than method。

**About Tweetbot3**
U just add uiview and uipangesturerecognizer into coustom tableview cell. and try this [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell)

Comment: I'm using a UICollectionViewCell and placing a UIScrollView inside of it. I've updated my answer, maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value during scroll using the [UIScrollViewDelegate method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll%3a) `scrollViewDidScroll:`

`self.scrollView.delegate = self;`

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x >= -50) {
        // Animate the star
        NSLog(@"Animate");
    }
}
```

Just be careful with your animation because the user could scroll back and forth between a `contentOffset` of 50 which may mess up your animation depending on how you've set it up.

Comment: The delegate is set and it is placed in the scrollViewDidScroll: The issue is that it's not always called when it reached that value. If I pull it really fast, it doesn't get called, and if I pull it really slow, it gets called.